# How to select a field with the ordered data on sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables:

```
Fixture:       Id  Time        ....
               3 2016-12-1 
               4 2016-12-8

FixtureStats:  Id  FixtureId PlayerId  Rating Assists  MarketValue
               1       3      33       8       2        300000
               2       4      33       5       1        250000
```

How can I select a summary of players' performance stats and get the most recent Marketvalue based on Fixture Time

```
    SELECT distinct s.PlayerId, 
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(s.Rating AS float)) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId),2) AS Rating, SUM(s.Assist) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId) AS Assists, 
    s.MarketValue  << what to write here 
     FROM dbo.FixtureStats AS s INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Player p ON s.PlayerId =p.Id INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture AS f ON s.FixtureId = f.Id
```

It's supposed to get the result

```
PlayerId Rating Assists Marketvalue
 33       6.5     3     250000           << 1 record for every single player
 34       8.5     1     660000
```

If I simply put s.MarketValue there, it will break the distinct,=> list all marketvalue for 1 PlayerId. Is there any way to get the latest marketvalue for every PlayerId ?

```
 PlayerId Rating Assists Marketvalue
     33       6.5     3     250000 
     33       6.5     3     300000    << repeated results
     ...
     34       xx     x       value1
     34       xx     x       value2
    ...
```

My only solution is to write a Scalar function but I'm afraid it would affect the performance.

Thanks all.

UPDATED:

I decided to move MarketValue field from FixtureStat to Player table and auto update the value to the most recent, this way will not make any conflict with aggregate functions on FixtureStat table, and less computation work on runtime.

```
SELECT distinct s.PlayerId, 
        ROUND(AVG(CAST(s.Rating AS float)) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId),2) AS Rating, SUM(s.Assist) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId) AS Assists, 
        p.MarketValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select x.PlayerId, x.Rating, x.Assists, MAX(x.MarketValue) from ( SELECT distinct s.PlayerId, 
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(s.Rating AS float)) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId),2) AS Rating, SUM(s.Assist) OVER(PARTITION BY s.PlayerId) AS Assists, 
    s.MarketValue 
     FROM dbo.FixtureStats AS s INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Player p ON s.PlayerId =p.Id INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture AS f ON s.FixtureId = f.Id ) x
    GROUP BY x.PlayerId, x.Rating, x.Assists, x.MarketValue
```

Comment: It's not right since Marketvalue is from most recent fixture. Also, if I put s.MarketValue on the select, it will break the Distinct

Comment: THanks for help, indeed my real sql statement is like your sql. but as stated above, using s.MarketValue will list all possible values for 1 Player, not getting a single latest value for 1 player. Also I think order by Fixture.Time desc is more suitable.   I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `row_number` ordering by `FixtureStats.Id`

```
SELECT playerid,
       rating,
       assists,
       marketvalue
FROM   (SELECT s.playerid,
               Round(Avg(Cast(s.rating AS FLOAT)) OVER(partition BY s.playerid), 2) AS Rating,
               Sum(s.assists) OVER(partition BY s.playerid) AS Assists,
               s.marketvalue,
               Row_number() OVER(partition BY s.playerid ORDER BY s.id DESC) row_num
        FROM  dbo.FixtureStats AS s
        INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON s.PlayerId =p.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture AS f ON s.fixtureid = f.id) t1
WHERE  row_num = 1
```

Hope this should help you out.